# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource app_icon could not be found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

I feel like I'm making a very simple mistake but I just can't figure it out right now. This is the full error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource app_icon could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)

In my `pubspec.yaml` file, I have:

```yaml
assets:
  - lib/assets/myapp_logo_1.png
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have:

```xml
<application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

My `res` folder has 6 different versions of a `minimap` folder. Inside each one there is an `ic_launcher.png` file.

[image]